# hyper-v pass-thru disks fail after migration or host reboot

Tags: hyper-v

I'm running a Hyper-V 2008R2 cluster with iSCSI backed storage. I'm using a mix of Cluster Shared Volumes for most VM's, but I use a couple pass-thru disks to iSCSI volumes for some larger data volumes.

The pass-thru volumes are frequently being mounted on the host and assigned a drive letter. This causes the volume to become unavailable in the guest. Sometimes I can manually remove the drive letter from the host and add it to the guest and the volume works again, but this doesn't always work. I can reliably reproduce this problem by live migrating the guest to a different host or rebooting the host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the way the pass-thru disk was configured. If you add the disk to the cluster resource that represents the guest manually, the host server will mount the volumes on the disk before bringing the guest online. This renders the disk unavailable inside the guest.

You can verify that you have this problem by looking at "Services and Applications" in the Failover Cluster Manager. Looks at the VM guest and find the list of "Disk Drives". If the "File System" is listed as NTFS, then the host has the volume open. If the "File System" is `<unknown>` then the volume is already configured correctly.

**The correct sequence for adding a pass-thru disk to a highly available VM (i.e., guest running on a clustered Hyper-V host) is a follows:**

1. Present the storage to the cluster. (Configure the iSCSI session, etc.)
2. Open Disk Management.

   - If this is a blank disk, right-click the disk and pick Initialize. Right-click again and take it Offline.
   - If this disk already has data on it that you want to preserve, right-click the disk and bring it Online, then right-click again and take it Offline.
3. Open the Failover Cluster Manager and navigate to Storage.
4. Click "Add a Disk" and select the disk.
5. Right-click the disk and pick Properties. Name the disk something useful. Also note the disk name above the volume list. You'll need this name later. (In this example, the disk is named Disk5.)
   [image]
6. Go to "Services and Applications" in the Failover Cluster Manager console and find your VM. Alternatively, open the Hyper-V management console.
7. Right-click the VM and pick Settings.
8. If the VM doesn't already have one, add a SCSI controller.
9. Add a new disk to the SCSI controller. Select the "Physical hard disk" option. Choose the disk name your found in step 5. Click OK.
10. Complete the disk configuration inside your guest.

**If you already have a volume configured incorrectly and you want to fix it:**

1. Shut down the guest.
2. Remove the pass-thru disk from the VM configuration.
3. Remove the disk resource from the VM in the "Services and Applications" screen of the Failover Cluster Manager console.
4. Open the VM configuration and add the pass-thru disk back. (See steps 5-10 above.)